# Creating configurable products with recurring options

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, recurring-billing, configurable-product

I need to sell configurable product (allowing to choose size and color) with recurring delivery that happens few time per year.

So first I have created One configurable product with recurring option ON and few simple products under it. 
But when I\’m trying to add it to the cart it says “Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote. “. I\’m only adding one configurable product that has recurring profile to the empty shopping cart.

Okay, I\’m trying another way - turning off recurring option for Configurable product and enabling it for simple products. 
Now it adds to card and I can complete checkout process, but in admin it show up as regular order without recurring profile.

Tried turning on recurring option for both: configurable and Simple product - the same error “Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. “

Are there any other options? What can you suggest?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished something similar to this.

Please not this isnt exactly an answer to your problem, but I see you dont have much help here, so Hopefully, if anything, this will get you another way of thinking about it.

You may be able to do this with Bundled products.

Lets say you are selling Tshirts.

Simple item Shirt
Simple item Color
Simple item Embroidery

Bundle item = Custom Tshirt

This will show the Custom Tshirt as a bundled item, and the user will select from the bundle options. For example, sometimes black tshirts are more expensive. So you could set up pricing for those options

Simple Item shirt = $20
Simple Item Color -
    Black = $5
    White = $0
Simple Item Embroidery = $20

This will allow the customer to create a customized order with specified options.

I apologize if this doesnt help at all, but perhaps it will give you an idea!